# Export a data frame to a text file in R

Tags: r

I want to export a data frame in a text file by R, but when I use the code as below, all the data in my output file become string.

```
write.table(docm,  file = "DoCM.txt", sep ="\t" ,row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqtqy.png) is my output data frame

How can I export my data frame without convert to the string?
thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting `quote=FALSE`:

```
write.table(mtcars,  file = "mtcars.txt", quote = FALSE, sep ="\t" ,row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

[image]